# Ajax favorite/unfavorite button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to implement some Ajax on a favourite/unfavourite button. The idea behind it is that when you click it a star changes to yellow and when you click it again, it changes back to grey and so on. It adds and deletes data from a DB.

before I had it like this

```
    <?php

include("classes/event.class.php");

$m = new Event();
$arrayAllEvents = $m->getNonFavo();
$arrayFavorites = $m->getFavo();

  $db = new db();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($arrayFavorites))
{
  $unfavoriteID = $row['f_id'];
  $uid = $_SESSION['u_id'];
}

if(isset($_POST['favorite_row'])) 
{
  $uid = $_SESSION['u_id'];
   $Fid = $_POST['id_to_be_favo'];
   if(!mysqli_query($db->conn, "INSERT INTO favorites (u_id, n_id, f_boolean) VALUES
        ('". $db->conn->real_escape_string($uid) ."' ,
        '". $db->conn->real_escape_string($Fid) ."' ,
        '". $db->conn->real_escape_string("1") ."')"))
   {
     echo mysqli_error($db->conn);
   }
}

if(isset($_POST['Unfavorite_row'])) 
{
  $unFid = $_POST['id_to_be_unfavo'];
    if(!mysqli_query($db->conn, "DELETE FROM favorites WHERE f_id ='".$unFid."'"))
    {
      echo mysqli_error($db);
    }
  }
?>
```

And the field was a php echo form

```
  <?php

    echo "<form method='post'>
          <input type ='hidden' name='id_to_be_favo'
          value='".$a['n_id']."' />
          <input type='submit' class='favoriteFalse' id='FavoBtn' name='favorite_row' value='favorite' />
          </form>

          <div class='clearfix'> </div>";       
  ?>
```

I'm trying to change the form to a button and use jQuery/Ajax to switch it.
I've been trying some different solutions I've found online, but none of them seem to work.

What would be the best way to implement this?

Kind regards

Comment: give the id  to your button value attribute, fetch it through jquery and send it to the php function to check that id have favorite already or not? if yes then something and if no then other thing.  if it based on user_id also then send both id to the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type='button' class='favorite' id='<?php echo $a['n_id']; ?>' value='favorite' />

<div class='clearfix'> </div>";
```

using

```
$(function() {
  $(".favorite").on("click".function() {
    $.post("whatever.php", {"favorite_row":this.id}, function(data) {
      $("#star").html('<img/>',{"src":data.fave==yes"?"true.png":"false.png"});
   }); 
});
```

Now return {"fave":"yes"} if favorited